# How to solve a problem with package linux-headers-4.15.0-47?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

Thank you for helping in advance,
I get all the time similar massage when I try to `sudo apt upgrade` or install sth.

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'linux-headers-4.15.0-47' is missing final newline E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

By typing `uname -r`
I get `4.15.0-51-generic`

I tried to do 'many things' but I need good soul to help me go through this.

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-150 linux-headers-4.4.0-150-generic linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic
  linux-modules-4.4.0-150-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-150-generic snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-55 linux-headers-4.15.0-55-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-157
  linux-headers-4.4.0-157-generic linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic linux-image-4.4.0-157-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-55-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-157-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-55-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-157-generic
  ubuntu-advantage-tools xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apport-gtk apt apt-transport-https apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data apturl apturl-common
  base-files bash bsdutils bzip2 ca-certificates console-setup console-setup-linux cpp-5 cups
  cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ppdc cups-server-common dbus
  dbus-x11 debconf debconf-i18n dkms dpkg dpkg-dev evince evince-common firefox firefox-locale-en
  fonts-opensymbol friendly-recovery fwupd g++-5 gcc-5 gcc-5-base geoclue-ubuntu-geoip
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gnome-software gnome-software-common grub-common grub-efi-amd64
  grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2-common gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common
  gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs hwdata imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 imagemagick-common
  intel-microcode iproute2 keyboard-configuration kmod libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libasan2
  libatomic1 libblkid1 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev
  libc6-i386 libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1
  libdbus-1-3 libdfu1 libdpkg-perl libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libexiv2-14 libexpat1
  libexpat1-dev libfdisk1 libfwupd1 libgcc-5-dev libgfortran3 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin
  libglib2.0-data libgomp1 libimage-magick-perl libimage-magick-q16-perl libitm1 libkmod2
  libldap-2.4-2 liblsan0 libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
  libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libmount1 libmpx0 libmysqlclient20 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb
  libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpam-systemd libpci3 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler58 libpq5 libquadmath0
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common
  libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze
  libreoffice-style-galaxy libreoffice-writer libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db
  libsmartcols1 libsnapd-glib1 libsqlite3-0 libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6 libsystemd0 libtsan0
  libubsan0 libudev1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9 libunity-settings-daemon1
  libuuid1 libuuid1:i386 libvdpau1 libwhoopsie0 libxnvctrl0 linux-firmware linux-generic
  linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-headers-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic
  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-libc-dev linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 locales login lshw
  mokutil mount multiarch-support mysql-common nvidia-settings openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
  opera-stable passwd patch pciutils policykit-desktop-privileges poppler-utils python-apt-common
  python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-distupgrade python3-problem-report python3-software-properties
  python3-uno python3-update-manager resolvconf rsyslog secureboot-db shim shim-signed snapd
  snapd-login-service software-properties-common software-properties-gtk sudo systemd systemd-sysv
  thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us tzdata
  ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-software ubuntu-standard udev unattended-upgrades unity
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-faces unity-schemas unity-services
  unity-settings-daemon uno-libs3 update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier
  update-notifier-common ure ureadahead usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk util-linux uuid-runtime
  vdpau-driver-all vim-common vim-tiny whoopsie
242 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/548 MB of archives.
After this operation, 609 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libquadmath0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgomp1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbluetooth3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'glib-networking-services' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'qml-module-qt-labs-settings:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxmuu1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ippusbxd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'emboss-lib' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdmapsharing-3.0-2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++-5-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'linux-headers-4.15.0-47' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Please add the full output of `sudo apt upgrade` to your question. Also make sure to run `sudo apt update` before running upgrade.

Comment: I don't know how to add things in a more convenient way. I'm kinda newbie.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` first? This step is very important!!!

Comment: Which release ? Please show `lsb_release -rc`

Comment: Yes i have run `sudo apt update` first. My realise is: Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial